# overridePackages of local nixpkgs' config to add new packages

Tags: haskell, nix, nixos

i'm looking for enlightenment on how to do the best way on my situation as follows:

1. I have a nixpkgs folder on my project, which I download from other repo. It located on my `theproject/front-plat/default.nix` then the code is look like this.

   `{ nixpkgsFunc ? import ./nixpkgs }: let nixpkgs = nixpkgsFunc ({ config = { ... }; lib = {...}; etc.`
2. In my `theproject/release.nix` I want to add a new packages which will be used for my built using the nixpkgs' front-plat. So the code looks like this.

   `{ front-plat ? import ./deps/front-plat {}}:
   let
     nixpkgs = front-platform.nixpkgs;
     packageCompiler = front-plat.compiler;
     config = rec { ... 
       packageOverrides = pkgs: rec {
         packageCompiler = pkgs.packageCompiler.override {
           overrides = self: super: rec {
             fronFrint = self.callPackage (import ./frontFrint { inherit front-plat; });
         };
       };
     };`

3    Which I assume, now i'm using the nixpkgs from the front-plat but i'm still not sure does my nixpkgs' packageCompiler already contains fronFrint package or not.

The question is, how can I add my new packages called "frontFrint" to the nixpkgs's packageCompiler. so that the packageCompiler can built fronFrint. for example in the end, the code will be 
 `in { front = pkgs.packageCompiler.frontFrint; }`

Comment: There's lots of complexity here and some implicit Nix expressions. Can you simplify an example, so it is self-contained?